# Coldfusion query mySQL won't select date fields

Tags: mysql, date, coldfusion

I have this code:

```
<cfquery name="getDate" datasource="myDataSource">
    SELECT *
    FROM TEST
</cfquery>
<cfoutput query="getDate">
    #aDate#
</cfoutput>
```

I have a mySQL database, with a table named Test that consists of one column, which is a date field.

This is a simplification of a bigger problem in that whenever I try to select records from the mySQL database that have dates in them, the query doesn't execute. If I remove the date fields from the query, they work fine.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: If you actually `cfdump` the query, does it show as blank?

Comment: what is the indication that the query does not execute?

Comment: As TRose said, providing the results of a cfdump (`<cfdump var="#getDate#">`) could be helpful. When you say, "the query doesn't execute" does it result in an error? If so what's the error message?

Lastly, what are the dates' field names in your table?

Comment: The page just stops processing at the query. I typed "Query start" before the cfquery and "Query successful" after the </cfquery> tag. "Query successful" doesn't show up. The page stops processing when it tries to query the database.

Comment: I tried using cfdump, but the page doesn't process far enough to reach it.

Comment: Additionally, how large is the table? You are currently selecting everything in it. This could take a very long time, or even be too big to hold in RAM.

Comment: What versions of CF and MySQL?

Comment: Following up on @TimJasko's comment, put a where clause of 1=2 in your query so that you don't have to worry about RAM and such.  If it executes, then, take it out and add `maxrows="1"` to your cfquery tag.

Comment: Oooor you could wrap everything in `cftry` and `cfcatch` tags, then dump the `cfcatch` to forcefully produce an error message.

Answer (score 1):

The table currently has about 50 records and only about 15 or so fields, so that's not the problem.

I identified the problem as being that some of the date fields in mySQL that were supposed to be empty had 0000:00:00 in them, and others had NULL.

I still don't know why that caused CF a problem, but the problem is fixed now.

It was especially weird because if I cfoutputted the SQL text in my cfm page, then copied the code generated and pasted it into the phpmyAdmin SQL box in mySQL, the queries worked fine every time.

Anywho, thanks for all the great suggestions!

Scott

Comment: Ahh yeah. I remember this about mySQL... in the ColdFusion Admin, you can actually specify a connection string to prevent this error - something like `zeroDateTime = null` - I forget what exactly it was - but it was for this very occurrence and it happened all the time before we discovered the fix. mySQL is a harsh mistress.

Comment: Addendum - `zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull`